# Ios get href tag from html

Tags: html, ios

I have a html code from which i want to get `<a href>` tag value.

```
<span class="meta">
    <span itemprop="author" class="meta-author"> 
        <a href="http://beta.morningnewsusa.com/author/kmnaing" title="Posts by James Kong" rel="author">
            James Kong
        </a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Right now i am using following code which returns nil:-

```
NSString *imgURL = [
    NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).parentNode.href",  
    touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y
]; 
NSString *urlToSave = [
    _webView1  stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:imgURL
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this code worked for me:-

```
NSString *imgURL = [
    NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f).href",
    touchPoint.x,
    touchPoint.y
];
```